# Trouble making a dataframe from API data

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
from pandas import json_normalize 
import pandas as pd

headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
headers['Authorization']= "Bearer token"
url = "https:link.com"
payload="""{
 "GradeIds" : [7,8],
 "ReportStartDate" : "2020-01-25T00:00:00",
 "ReportEndDate" : "2020-02-27T00:00:00"
          }"""
response = requests.request( 'POST',url, headers=headers, data=payload)
parsed = json.loads(response.text)
print(parsed)
len(parsed)

df = json_normalize(parsed)
```

However, the output is a bit messy and the json_normalize function is unable to make it into a clean dataframe. The following is a sample output from the API from `print(parsed)`:

`[{'grade': {'id': 7, 'name': 'stuff1', 'type': 'data'}, 'endOfDayPrices': [{'reportDate': '2020-01-27T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 3.9}, {'reportDate': '2020-01-28T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 3.95},  {'reportDate': '2020-01-28T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 1.05}, {'reportDate': '2020-01-29T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 1.1}, {'reportDate': '2020-01-30T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 0.85}}]`

When printing `df` the dataframe I get the following:

```
 endOfDayPrices  grade.id grade.name  \                            
 0  [{'reportDate': '2020-01-27T00:00:00', 'month'...         7      data
 1  [{'reportDate': '2020-01-27T00:00:00', 'month'...         8      data
```

When checking the length of this list `len(parsed)` it says there is only 2, grade and endofDayPrices.

Does anyone know how to unpack this list and have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
grade    reportDate          price
7      2020-01-27T00:00:00   2.3
7      2020-01-28T00:00:00   3.95

,etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your `json` to be:

```
In [1977]: l = [{'grade': {'id': 7, 'name': 'stuff', 'type': 'data'}, 'endOfDayPrices': [{'reportDate': '2020-01-27T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 2.3}, {'reportDate': '2020-01-28T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 3
      ...: .95}, {'reportDate': '2020-01-29T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 2.5}, {'reportDate': '2020-01-30T00:00:00', 'month': '2020-03-01T00:00:00', 'price': 4.0}]}]
```

You can do this:

```
In [2079]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [2083]: for i in l:
      ...:     d1 = {}
      ...:     reportDate = []
      ...:     price = []
      ...:     grade = []
      ...:     d1['grade'] = i['grade']['id']
      ...:     for j in i['endOfDayPrices']:
      ...:         reportDate.append(j['reportDate'])
      ...:         price.append(j['price'])
      ...:     d1['reportDate'] = reportDate
      ...:     d1['price'] = price
      ...:     df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(d1))
      ...: 
      ...: 

In [2084]: df
Out[2084]: 
    grade           reportDate  price
0       7  2020-01-27T00:00:00  3.900
1       7  2020-01-28T00:00:00  3.950
2       7  2020-01-29T00:00:00  4.000
3       7  2020-01-30T00:00:00  4.000
4       7  2020-01-31T00:00:00  3.900
5       7  2020-02-03T00:00:00  3.600
6       7  2020-02-04T00:00:00  3.700
7       7  2020-02-05T00:00:00  3.700
8       7  2020-02-06T00:00:00  3.350
9       7  2020-02-07T00:00:00  3.400
10      7  2020-02-10T00:00:00  3.300
11      7  2020-02-11T00:00:00  3.500
12      7  2020-02-12T00:00:00  3.500
13      7  2020-02-13T00:00:00  3.500
14      7  2020-02-14T00:00:00  3.550
15      7  2020-02-18T00:00:00  3.350
16      7  2020-02-19T00:00:00  3.150
17      7  2020-02-20T00:00:00  3.550
18      7  2020-02-21T00:00:00  3.554
19      7  2020-02-24T00:00:00  3.555
20      7  2020-02-25T00:00:00  3.555
21      7  2020-02-26T00:00:00  2.900
22      7  2020-02-27T00:00:00  2.700
0       8  2020-01-27T00:00:00  1.200
1       8  2020-01-28T00:00:00  1.050
2       8  2020-01-29T00:00:00  1.100
3       8  2020-01-30T00:00:00  0.850
4       8  2020-01-31T00:00:00  0.900
5       8  2020-02-03T00:00:00  0.650
6       8  2020-02-04T00:00:00  0.800
7       8  2020-02-05T00:00:00  1.250
8       8  2020-02-06T00:00:00  0.900
9       8  2020-02-07T00:00:00  0.950
10      8  2020-02-10T00:00:00  0.800
11      8  2020-02-11T00:00:00  0.950
12      8  2020-02-12T00:00:00  0.800
13      8  2020-02-13T00:00:00  0.850
14      8  2020-02-14T00:00:00  0.850
15      8  2020-02-18T00:00:00  0.800
16      8  2020-02-19T00:00:00  1.000
17      8  2020-02-20T00:00:00  0.933
18      8  2020-02-21T00:00:00  1.015
19      8  2020-02-24T00:00:00  1.021
20      8  2020-02-25T00:00:00  1.020
21      8  2020-02-26T00:00:00  0.600
22      8  2020-02-27T00:00:00  1.000
```

Comment: it outputs the wrong grade it gives 8 for all of them, do you know why that is?

Comment: @MichelleM Please check my updated answer.